# R: abc<-c(1:15) vs abcd<-1:15

Tags: r, list, vector, combiners

What is the difference between the following commands:

```
abc <- 1:15
abcd <- c(1:15)
abc
abcd
```

The output is:

```
> abc <- 1:15
> abcd <- c(1:15)
> abc
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
> abcd
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: No difference. Just unnecessary additional `c()` in your second attempt. Just read the manual please.

Comment: You can use `identical(abc, abcd)` in such cases to check if both are _exactly_ equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c()` is a function to concatenate vectors. 
In your example you only supply one vector - `1:15` so they are functionally the same.
You need `c()` if you want to concatenate two or more ranges, for example to not have 13 in your vector: `c(1:12, 14:15)`